# Where are wp's add_rewrite_rule rules saved?

Tags: php, wordpress

Where are Wordpress's add_rewrite_rule rules saved?

I cannot see them in .htaccess file.  Are they in mySql?  If so, which table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They are stored in the `{your_prefix}options` table (`wp_options` by default) under `rewrite_rules`.